# how to add persistent route on a container

Tags: 18.10, etc, container

Since up route add [-net|-host] / gw  dev  going into cd /etc/network/interfaces doesn't work.
How can i add persistent routes so the route is still there when it boots. I was told /etc/systemd/network is a good way but still confusing in a way

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is now based on Netplan service to configure network. Based on the official documentation https://netplan.io/examples, here a basic sample :

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     addresses:
       - 192.168.1.10/24
     #gateway4:    # unset, since we configure routes below
     routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.1.1
         metric: 100
       - to: 192.168.2.0/24
         via: 192.168.1.2
         metric: 100
```

This file should exist or must be created under `/etc/netplan/` with a .yaml extension (e.g. /etc/netplan/config.yaml). Don't forget to use command `sudo netplan apply` to apply configuration.